# Reading a file in python and creating a list turns out to an empty list

Tags: python

I am using the following code to read from a file:

```
G={}
for line in fin: # load data, create adj lists
    lst=[]
    size= len(line)
    i=0
    while (i<size):
        if line[i] in ' \t\r\n': pass
        else:
            lst.append(int(line[i:i+2].strip()))
            i=i+1
        i=i+1
    G[lst[0] ]=lst[1:]

print(G)
```

But G always turns out to be empty."foo1,txt" contains the following data:

```
1 15
2 6 10
3 10
4 9
5
```

Comment: If `G` is *always* empty, then your `for` loop body never executed. That in turn means that `fin` is *empty* or has been iterated over to the end before you got to the code you've shown here.

Comment: Just tested with that code and that exact file data. Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, its most pythonic i think:

```
fin = open("foo1.txt")
G={}
for line in fin: # load data, create adj lists
    lst = line.split()
    lst = [int(x) for x in lst]
    G[lst[0] ]=lst[1:]
print(G)
```

Comment: This doesn't convert the values into integers. It may be an improvement on the existing code, but won't work any better when there is no iteration going on *at all*.

Comment: `lst = map(int, line.split())` would be better still, or for Python 3 `lst = [int(v) for v in line.split()]`.

Comment: You right, edited code, didn't noticed there was conversion going on.

Comment: Remove the argument from the `str.split()` call; why limit yourself to just single spaces when the argument-less version does stripping as well, and can handle arbitrary width whitespace?

Comment: And this still doesn't answer the OP question. We cannot answer it because what was done to `fin` before (or even what type of object it is) is missing from the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have writen alternte code for appending data to list from file, you can refer if you want this code:

```
   f = open('filename')

   dic = []

   for l in f:

       v = l.split(' ')
       v= map(lambda s: s.strip(), v)


      dic=dic+v


  print dic
```

output:

```
   ['1', '15', '2', '6', '10', '3', '10', '4', '9', '5', '']
```